# How should I structure my DoFn to ensure my output data is synchronous?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, apache-beam

I have implemented a stateful and timely DoFn in Apache Beam python SDK.

```py
class WriteToFirestore(beam.DoFn):
    EXPIRY_TIMER = TimerSpec('expiry', TimeDomain.WATERMARK)
    BUFFER_STATE = BagStateSpec('buffer', StrUtf8Coder())

    def setup(self):
        from google.cloud import firestore

        self.firestore = firestore

    def process(self, element,
                timer=beam.DoFn.TimerParam(EXPIRY_TIMER),
                window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam,
                buffer=beam.DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER_STATE)):

        timer.set(window.end + 1)

        buffer.add(element[1])

    @on_timer(EXPIRY_TIMER)
    def expiry(self, buffer=beam.DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER_STATE)):
        events = buffer.read()

        for event in events:
            data = json.loads(event, object_hook=self.object_hook)
            firebase_project_id = "<firebase project ID>"
            self.write_to_firestore(data, firebase_project_id)

        buffer.clear()

    def write_to_firestore(self, data, firebase_project_id):
        self.firestore_client = self.firestore.Client(
            project=firebase_project_id)

        collection_ref = self.firestore_client.collection("<collection name>")
        collection_ref.add(data)
```

The desired behaviour is that I would like to add a document to firestore every second. This is why I chose to use a stateful DoFn and not rely on windowing.

The above code batches the events instead of continuously adding to firestore.

```
element 1:
  data: <some data>
  timestamp: 16-12-2023 00:00:00
element 2:
  data: <some data>
  timestamp: 16-12-2023 00:00:01
```

Would element 1 have an expiry trigger time of `16-12-2023 00:00:01` and would element 2 have an expiry trigger time of `16-12-2023 00:00:02` or am I mistaken?

What I am trying to achieve is to ingest elements at 1 second intervals, wait until the timer reaches the end of window + 1 second (buffering to ensure synchronisation) then add to firestore. Is this possible with my current approach?